# Can't get gridSearchCV to work for hmmlearn estimator

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, hmmlearn

I've got a hmm which I can train by passing the fit function a list 'merged' of all training sequences concatenated after each other, and a list 'all_lengths' of all of the individual sequence lengths

model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=3).fit(np.atleast_2d(merged).T, all_lengths)

This works, but I cant to determine the optimal n_components using sklearn's gridsearchCV, which keeps giving me errors if I try the following:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'n_components': [1,2,3]}]
test = GridSearchCV(hmm.MultinomialHMM(), tuned_parameters, cv=5,)
test.fit(np.atleast_2d(merged).T, all_lengths)
```

outputs

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [515031, 28923]
```

The 515031 relates to the length of merged, and 28923 is the length of all_lengths

Comment: Yes, thats the error. The number of samples in X should be equal to length of y.

Comment: I understand, but the hmmlearn estimator doesn't accept an array of samples as input. It needs to have them concatenated to a single list

Comment: Can you please post examples of your data. Also is the same data working for hmmlearn without gridSearch? If you say that it should be concatenated to single list, then why the shape is 515031 or 28923?